# Regex match one occurrence of a character while matching 2 of another

Tags: javascript, regex

As the question says, I'm trying to match one occurrence of a character and at the same time 2 occurrences of another. For example, in the string `"_Hell_o"` I would like to match the first `"_"` there and in the case of `"++Hello"` I would like to match exactly both `"+"`. Basically a function like this:

```
function change(str){
    console.log(str.replace(/[_+{2}]/, ''));

change("++Hello");
change("_Hello");
change("+Hello");
```

And the outputs to be

```
>>> Hello
>>> Hello
>>> +Hello
```

But that function does not work

Comment: why you don'y use two replace it can be more easier

Comment: `console.log(str.replace(/_|\+{2,2}/g, ''));`

Comment: If you only want to replace the first occurance of both, you can't use a single regex.

Comment: Note on regexes: Many of the special characters in regexes, including `{` and `}`, don't apply inside character classes. So your regex will actually match any one (and only one) of the five characters `_`, `+`, `{`, `}` or `2`. Compare with `[_+]{2}`, which will match `__` or `_+` or `+_` or `++`.

Answer (score 4):

`/^_{1}|\+{2}/g` does the trick.

```js
function change(str){
    console.log(str.replace(/^_{1}|\+{2}/g, ''));
}

change("++Hello");
change("+++Hello");
change("_Hell__o");
change("___Hello");
change("+Hello");
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! That's certainly cleaner.

Comment: `For example, in the string "_Hell_o" I would like to match the first "_"` Your regex matches all `_`

Comment: Well, I assume he means the first _ or ++.  And by first, he means the first one found. In a global sense, the next match picks up where the last match left off. In that case, it can never find _both_ globally, using the anchor `^`. So, if he wanted to make `a_b++c_d++` look like `abc_d++` it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your problem using two replace for example :

```js
var array = ["++Hello", "_Hello", "+Hello"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i].replace(/\+{2}/, '').replace(/_(.*)/, '$1'))
}
```

Comment: This is the only way if OP just wants to replace first. +1

Comment: @sln Not really... You can always use the `^` and match from the start.

Comment: Why not just do `array[i].replace('++', '').replace('_', '')`?

Comment: @DavidKnipe this is can replace all the occurence consider you have `_Hell_o` if you use your way you will get `Hello` and this is not what the op ask :)

Comment: @YCF_L That's not true. I just tried it (in Firefox). Furthermore, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace says "Only the first occurrence will be replaced." in the case where the first argument is a string.

Comment: @DavidKnipe i think your solution can also solve this problem, you can post it like an answer please maybe it can help the op :)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace('++', '').replace('_', '')
```

Simplified version of the answer by YCF_L. Like YCF_L's answer, it will remove the first occurrence of `++` (if any) and the first occurrence of `_` (if any).